# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 to have value 8 but received input with shape [None, 1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, openai-api

I'm training a model for the OpenAI lunarLander-v2 environment. I've succesfully done this using a Sequential model, but when trying to use the functional model, I get some errors with tensorshapes being incompatible.
Here is the code for the Agent class, the issue I think has to do with the shape of the done_list and next_states being incompatible, but I'm not sure how to reshape these tensors for it to work.

```
class DQAgent(Agent):
def __init__(self, env, config):
    Agent.__init__(self, env, config)
    
    self.memory = deque(maxlen=self.config.memory_size)
    self.model = self.initialize()

def initialize(self):
    
    inputs = Input(shape=(8,))
    
    dense = Dense(self.config.layer_size * self.config.input_layer_mult, activation = relu)
    x = dense(inputs)
    x = Dense(self.config.layer_size, activation = relu)(x)
    
    outputs = layers.Dense(self.action_space_size, activation = linear)(x)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs, name = self.name)

    model.compile(loss = mean_squared_error, optimizer = Adam(lr = self.config.learning_rate))
    model.summary()

    return model

def policyAct(self, state):
    predicted_actions = self.model.predict(state)
    return np.argmax(predicted_actions[0])

def addToMemory(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
    self.memory.append((self, state, action, reward, next_state, done))
    
def sampleFromMemory(self):
    sample = np.random.sample(self.memory, self.config.batch_size)
    return sample

def extractFromSample(self, sample):
    states = np.array([i[0] for i in sample])
    actions = np.array([i[1] for i in sample])
    rewards = np.array([i[2] for i in sample])
    next_states = np.array([i[3] for i in sample])
    done_list = np.array([i[4] for i in sample])
    states = np.squeeze(states)
    next_states = np.squeeze(next_states)
    
    
    return np.squeeze(states), actions, rewards, next_states, done_list
    
def updateReplayCount(self):
    self.config.replay_counter += 1
    self.config.replay_counter = self.replay_counter % self.config.replay_step_size

def learnFromMemory(self):
    if len(self.memory) < self.config.batch_size or self.config.replay_counter != 0:
        return
    if np.mean(self.training_episode_rewards[-10:]) > 100:
        return
    sample = self.sampleFromMemory()

    states, actions, rewards, next_states, done_list = self.extractFromSample(sample)
    targets = rewards + self.config.gamma * (np.amax(self.model.predict_on_batch(next_states), 
                                                     axis=1)) * (1 - (done_list))
    
    target_vec = self.model.predict_on_batch(states)
    indexes = np.array([i for i in range(self.config.batch_size)])
    target_vec[[indexes], [actions]] = targets
    self.model.fit(states, target_vec, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    
def save(self, name):
    self.model.save(name)
```

Similar code works fine when creating the model using the Sequential API instead of the functional.
I'm very new to this, and to SO as well, any help is greatly appreciated.

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 8) for input Tensor("input_10:0", shape=(None, 8), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1).
> ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_72 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 8 but received input with shape [None, 1]

The model from the sequential implementation, which runs with no issues (the rest of the code is the same)

```
def initialize_model(self):
    model = Sequential()
    
   
    model.add(Dense(self.config.layer_size*self.config.input_layer_mult, input_dim = self.observation_space_dim, activation=relu))
    
    
    for i in range(self.config.deep_layers):
        model.add(Dense(self.config.layer_size, activation=relu))
    
    
    model.add(Dense(self.action_space_dim, activation=linear))
    
    
    model.compile(loss=mean_squared_error, optimizer=Adam(lr=self.config.learning_rate))

    print(model.summary())
    
    return model
```

Comment: You are giving different input shapes to each model (8 vs self.observation_space_dim), that is why it errors, it has nothing to do with the model being functional or sequential.

Comment: observation_space_dim is size 8 though?

Comment: from debugging I think it has something to do with needing to reshape done_list and next_states to be compatible tensorshapes, am i completely off base here?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512293/input-dense-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-invalid-shape),
Input shape should be (1, )